# HP Slate 7 android app compatibility

Tags: android, google-play

I am writing an android app specifically for use with the HP Slate 7 and when I import the apk to Google Play it states that it is not compatible with the HP Slate 7 even though I have fully tested it on the device itself.  I have included the parts of my AndroidManifest.xml file below showing what Android says they filter by and you can see that I have tried explicitly to NOT require certain features to get it to work.  Any ideas why my app is showing as not compatible?

```
<supports-screens
android:anyDensity="true"
android:largeScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:resizeable="true"
android:smallScreens="true"
android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="9"
android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.CAMERA" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.AUTOFOCUS" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.PORTRAIT" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.TOUCHSCREEN" android:required="false" /> 

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: Try changing the `android:name` values in `<uses-feature>` to be all lowercase, as they are supposed to be.

Comment: Looks like removing the camera permission allows it to be compatible with the HP Slate 7.  Does anyone know how to determine why Google Play doesn't think the Slate has a camera or to at least contact them?

Comment: Did you change `android.hardware.CAMERA` to `android.hardware.camera` in the `<uses-feature>`? Then the permission should not matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values for `android:name` in `<uses-feature>` are case-sensitive. Having the wrong case will cause the Play Store to ignore your request.